# Visual Basic 6.0, comprobar que no se recoja más de una ID

Tags: condiciones, vb6, id

estoy haciendo un código con Visual Basic 6.0 en el que tengo que enviar datos a un programa externo para que cargue dichos datos allí, todo funciona bien, pero es obligatorio que recoja la id del documento, si no tengo seleccionado documento me debe mostrar una ventana de error y no hacer nada, si tengo un documento seleccionado me recoge su id y hace su trabajo, y si tengo más de un documento seleccionado también debe mostrar error y no hacer nada. ¿Cómo se podría comprobar esto? Lo siguiente es un ejemplo de lo que hace mi código.

```
queryString = "p_entidad=" & ID_entidad & "&p_usuario=" & ID_usuario & "&p_cargo=" & ID_usuario_cargo & "&doc=" & ID_doc
```

Las ID aparecen como números (ID_doc=1234 por ejemplo) por lo que la parte de comprobar que esté seleccionado o no sería tan fácil como hacer un condicional que lo compare con cero, pero no se cómo comprobar que esté seleccionado más de uno.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Tienes que poner más código, hay que apreciar desde donde viene ID_doc